# Народный фольклор

Tags: лингвистика

Как вы думаете, выражение "народный фольклор" — это тавтология или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спорный вопрос. "Народный" может иметь несколько значений, из которых как минимум два применимы к нашему случаю:

~1. Принадлежащий всему народу. Развивать н-ое хозяйство. Разбазаривать н-ые богатства. Беречь н-ое добро.
~2.Тесно связанный с народом, соответствующий духу народа, его культуре, мировоззрению. Творчество этого художника глубоко народно.
(БТС Кузнецова)

Поскольку в "фольклор" элемент "фольк" явно тяготеет к первому из двух названных значений, то использование "народный" во втором значении выглядит вполне правомерным.

Answer (score 4):

Народный фольклор - это, конечно, плеоназм. (Тавтология - вид плеоназма, повтор однокоренных слов). Фольклор - это устное народное творчество. Избыточность налицо. Но в языке есть устоявшиеся сочетания, в которых хотя и есть избыточность, но они уже не считаются ошибочными. Например, спуститься вниз, подняться наверх, период времени, экспонат выставки и др. Насколько ошибочно сочетание "народный фольклор" на сегодняшний день? На мой взгляд, этот ошибка. Но из разряда тех, которые могут перестать быть ошибочными.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, да, это неоправданная тавтология. Так как фольклор - это и есть народное творчество. И другим фольклор вряд ли может быть, он всегда народный.